# Plot multiple datasets in the same corner plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if it is possible to plot more than one dataset together using [corner plot](https://corner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Please don't suggest to use seaborn pairplot.

Here the script from the documentation, it is a simple corner plot:

```
import corner
import numpy as np

ndim, nsamples = 2, 10000
np.random.seed(42)
samples = np.random.randn(ndim * nsamples).reshape([nsamples, ndim])
figure = corner.corner(samples)
```

and the result:
[image]

Now, I would like to plot a second dataset, maybe with a different color, over the three images above. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is how:

```
figure = corner.corner(samples)
corner.corner(samples2,fig=figure)
```

Comment: How does one suppress the plotting from the first call to `corner.corner()`?

Answer (score 0):

Below is some code to overlay multiple sample sets in one corner plot, with a legend.

[image]

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Demo to overlay multiple corners on top of each other"""
import corner
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

CORNER_KWARGS = dict(
    smooth=0.9,
    label_kwargs=dict(fontsize=16),
    title_kwargs=dict(fontsize=16),
    quantiles=[0.16, 0.84],
    levels=(1 - np.exp(-0.5), 1 - np.exp(-2), 1 - np.exp(-9 / 2.)),
    plot_density=False,
    plot_datapoints=False,
    fill_contours=True,
    show_titles=True,
    max_n_ticks=3,
)


def overlaid_corner(samples_list, sample_labels):
    """Plots multiple corners on top of each other"""
    # get some constants
    n = len(samples_list)
    _, ndim = samples_list[0].shape
    max_len = max([len(s) for s in samples_list])
    cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('gist_rainbow', n)
    colors = [cmap(i) for i in range(n)]

    plot_range = []
    for dim in range(ndim):
        plot_range.append(
            [
                min([min(samples_list[i].T[dim]) for i in range(n)]),
                max([max(samples_list[i].T[dim]) for i in range(n)]),
            ]
        )

    CORNER_KWARGS.update(range=plot_range)

    fig = corner.corner(
        samples_list[0],
        color=colors[0],
        **CORNER_KWARGS
    )

    for idx in range(1, n):
        fig = corner.corner(
            samples_list[idx],
            fig=fig,
            weights=get_normalisation_weight(len(samples_list[idx]), max_len),
            color=colors[idx],
            **CORNER_KWARGS
        )

    plt.legend(
        handles=[
            mlines.Line2D([], [], color=colors[i], label=sample_labels[i])
            for i in range(n)
        ],
        fontsize=20, frameon=False,
        bbox_to_anchor=(1, ndim), loc="upper right"
    )
    plt.savefig("corner.png")
    plt.close()


def get_normalisation_weight(len_current_samples, len_of_longest_samples):
    return np.ones(len_current_samples) * (len_of_longest_samples / len_current_samples)


def main():
    ndim, nsamples = 3, 10000
    samples = np.random.randn(ndim * nsamples).reshape([nsamples, ndim])

    overlaid_corner(
        [samples * 3, samples * 2, samples],
        ["samples x 3", "samples x 2", "samples"]
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: But it does not scale the 1D histogram for the 1st sample correctly!

Comment: @deltasata, not sure what you mean? Do you have an example?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was not clear. Here I am concerned about the correctness (and appearance) of the 1D histograms. In this example why is not the 1st sample weighted with respect to `max_len`? Anyway, weighting here is equivalent to using `hist_kwargs=dict(density=True)` in `corner.corner()`. However, I find a bug in either case. The y range of the 1D histograms are reset after drawing the histogram for each sample. So if you do not draw the sample which has tallest histogram at the last you will see that it overshoots! Try passing samples NOT at the last! This must be a bug.